# sporing boot postgresql not creating datasource

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

SO i have a spring boot application, and configured postgresql, as below

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:dburl
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=XXX
```

But I get failure on application start up that a datasource is not created

```
No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available
```

I decided to create a datasource bean instead:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        // Create and configure the DataSource here
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/your-database");
        dataSource.setUsername("your-username");
        dataSource.setPassword("your-password");

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

This seems to create the datasource connection.

But i dont understand why i cannot create the datasource from the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your given sample you are missing port number for Postgres.

It is very simple to connect to Postgres using spring boot. Try following -

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my-db
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show us your dependencies? If using Maven as your build tool, please check to see if you have this (please add, if you don't and try again):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```